# Error: The getter 'pause/stop/play' isn't defined for the type 'MediaControl' when following audio_service tutorial

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

I am following the audio_service tutorial for an already existing project of mine.
I tried to implement the AudioPlayerTask from [this section](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/wiki/Tutorial#updating-the-ui-in-response-to-state-changes), and have imported

```
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
```

But I get the following errors:

```
error: The getter 'stop' isn't defined for the type 'MediaControl'. (undefined_getter at [project] lib/model/AudioPlayerTask.dart:11)
error: The getter 'pause' isn't defined for the type 'MediaControl'. (undefined_getter at [project] lib/model/AudioPlayerTask.dart:11)
error: The getter 'stop' isn't defined for the type 'MediaControl'. (undefined_getter at [project] lib/model/AudioPlayerTask.dart:21)
error: The getter 'pause' isn't defined for the type 'MediaControl'. (undefined_getter at [project] lib/model/AudioPlayerTask.dart:21)
error: The getter 'stop' isn't defined for the type 'MediaControl'. (undefined_getter at [project] lib/model/AudioPlayerTask.dart:43)
error: The getter 'pause' isn't defined for the type 'MediaControl'. (undefined_getter at [project] lib/model/AudioPlayerTask.dart:43)
error: The getter 'play' isn't defined for the type 'MediaControl'. (undefined_getter at [project] lib/model/AudioPlayerTask.dart:54)
error: The getter 'stop' isn't defined for the type 'MediaControl'. (undefined_getter at [project] lib/model/AudioPlayerTask.dart:54)
```

I haven't added any other code from the tutorial yet, but unless I'm overlooking something I would expect this to have no errors. What am I missing?

Comment: What version of audio_service do you have? I just tried adding it to a fresh project, then pasting in the code from that portion of the tutorial and I saw no such errors. Perhaps you have an older version that didn't yet have those properties on MediaControl?

Comment: You are absolutely right, that was exactly my problem. I had added Audio_service to pubspec from a youtube video, and that had me using version 0.11.1. It works after updating, thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!